# Clearing cache with Selenium ChromeDriver ChromeOptions

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-cache

Currently using `var driver = new ChromeDriver(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);`

We want to replace it as if we did:
[image]

With something like:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AggressiveCacheDiscard = true; // how??
options.ChromeDriverDirectory = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory; // how??
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But how do we do that?  The goal being to set options that will ensure the cache/cookies are always cleared completely (From the beginning of time, as Chrome says) and that the directory is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this through Selenium. If you are trying to make sure everything is cleared at the beginning of starting a Chrome driver, or when you are done, then you don't need to do anything. Every time you initialize a webdriver, it is a brand new instance with no cache, cookies, or history. Every time you terminate the driver, all these are cleared.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought Selenium did.  This intermittent problem we are seeing must be related to something else.